# Call a function while clicking outside ngx bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

Is it possible to call a function when we click outside ngx bootstrap modal window . if we click on the faded region I want to make a function call.

Comment: make a `<div class="example">...` (thats the "faded region" where the user can click) and then `$(".example).click(func.....`  (with jQuery). When you want to  call the function if the user clicks anywhere but in the modal use the [`not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you, you are talking about way different plugin, it's not ngx-bootstrap as I thought (because it was listed in tags), but angular2-modal. I don't know that plugin and there is nothing in documentation. You will probably have to build some custom code or change the plugin.

Comment: Sorry I am using ngx bootstrap modal only .. I have added wrong plunker .. Will update and add

Comment: I assume, you are going to close modal when user click outside and that time you need to call your function. is that right ?

Comment: Yes exactly that's wat I want